# Problem with input unit price into Gram scale

Tags: scale

I am using a GRAM electronic scale and programming in C# to input a unit price onto the scale. According to the documentation, the byte sequence "77 f9 00 00 04 00 00 2b 5c 01" is used to represent a unit price of 111, and this has been successfully implemented. However, i am unclear about how the part "00 00 2b 5c" of this sequence translates to the unit price of 111, as stated in the documentation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, basically you don't fully understand the manufacture's docs. This question has nothing to do with C# or programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These docs are representing bytes in hexadecimal. [Converting](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) the price data bytes in the example (`0x00002b5c`) to decimal returns `11100`, your price in cents ($111.00).